# @PreAuthorize not working for some of my @controllers spring security 3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization

**I am using spring-security-3.1 and implemented the resource based security on my @controllers**
*it works fine with my controller but it is not working three of my controller which are same as other @controller and i am using the @PreAuthorize like this :-*

```
@RequestMapping(value="/jobOpenings.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('jobOpenings', 'edit')")
    private String jobOpenings(HttpSession session) {
        logger.info("jobOpenings() method called!");
        if(session.getAttribute("requisitionId") != null) {
            session.removeAttribute("requisitionId");
        }
        if(session.getAttribute("candidateIds") != null) {
            session.removeAttribute("candidateIds");
        }
        return "job_openings/job_openings";
    }
```

**but it is not working and it is not even hitting my permission handle class. Please help**

Comment: It will only work on public/protected methods not for private methods.